# what are the exact steps to restore a replicate set from a secondary filesystem snapshot

Tags: mongodb

as the subject states, could somebody please tell me the exact steps necessary to restore a mongod replicate set from a file system snapshot. i see directions on how to do the snapshot, but i need to test the recovery process. also, is it really necessary to do the fsyncLock/Unlock before and after taking the snapshot ?

thanks !

Comment: Can you post a link to the instructions you're using to create the snapshot?

Comment: If you don't do fsyncLock/Unlock your snapshot will be corrupt because the mongod server will continue to modify the files while you are creating the snapshot.

Comment: I'd suggest moving this to dba.stackexchange.com, as this isn't a software development question.

Comment: thanks folks. i will try and move over to dba.stackexchange.com.